# full implementation of pagination using cursors

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

can anybody provide a working implementation of pagination using cursors?

Most examples are about how to access the next pages. I am having trouble accessing previous pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get(self):
    echo = self.response.out.write
    limit = 10
    if self.is_logged_in():
        curs = Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('curs'))

        query = Postdb.query()

        if self.request.get('type') == 'prev':
            query_reverse = query.order(-Postdb.key)

            posts, cursor, more = query_reverse.fetch_page(limit, start_cursor=curs.reversed())

            echo('<ol>')
            for post in reversed(posts):
                echo('<li><a href="'+post.key.urlsafe()+'">'+post.title+'</a></li>')
            echo('</ol>')

            if more and cursor:
                echo('<a href="?type=prev&curs='+cursor.reversed().urlsafe()+'">prev</a> ')

            echo('<a href="?type=next&curs='+curs.urlsafe()+'">next</a>')
        else:
            query_forward = query.order(Postdb.key)

            posts, cursor, more = query_forward.fetch_page(limit, start_cursor=curs)

            echo('<ol>')
            for post in posts:
                echo('<li><a href="'+post.key.urlsafe()+'">'+post.title+'</a></li>')
            echo('</ol>')

            if self.request.get('curs') != '':
                echo('<a href="?type=prev&curs='+curs.urlsafe()+'">prev</a> ')

            if more and cursor:
                echo('<a href="?type=next&curs='+cursor.urlsafe()+'">next</a>')

        echo('<br><br><a href="/auth/posts/list">start</a>')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a limited number of different queries, you might want to look at

https://bitbucket.org/viur/server/src/1b739a5e4ff1c2e3ce8933603a6faf32b364e708/indexes.py?at=master

This class handles all the cursor stuff for you and allows efficient random access to pages (ie. you can directly jump to page n, instead of having to click "next" n times).